# ros3djs does not display the laser scan via rosbridge

Tags: javascript, web, ros

I'm facing a problem with the laser scan display using ros3djs and rosbridge. when I record  a bagfile of the scan and run it on my laptop my browser display it perfectly, but when I try the same code on my jetson (nvidia nx) nothing displayed on the browser. and I tried to test the three.js & viewer from ros3djs by creating a simple Three JS cube and it was displayed. What am I missing here?.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this maybe a little bit late but here are the steps I needed to get LaserScan to work properly in ros3djs.

1. Make sure that the rosbridge server is running (`roslaunch rosbridge_server rosbridge_websocket.launch`)
2. Make sure that the tf2_web_republisher node is running (`rosrun tf2_web_republisher tf2_web_republisher`)
3. Of course also make sure that your LaserScan publisher is running, this depends on your specific configuration

You can now connect your TFClient and LaserScan subscribers in roslibjs and ros3djs like so:

```
const ros = new ROSLIB.Ros({
    url : 'ws://<your_address>:9090'
})

ros.on('connection', function() {
    console.log('Connected to websocket server.');
})

ros.on('error', function(error) {
    console.log('Error connecting to websocket server: ', error);
})

ros.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection to websocket server closed.');
})


const viewer = new ROS3D.Viewer({
    divID : 'scan',
    width : 800,
    height : 600,
    background: '#444444',
    antialias : true
})


const tfClient = new ROSLIB.TFClient({
    ros : ros,
    angularThres : 0.01,
    transThres : 0.01,
    rate : 10.0
})


const scanclient = new ROS3D.LaserScan({
    ros: ros,
    topic: '/scan',
    tfClient: tfClient,
    rootObject: viewer.scene,
    material: { size: 0.05, color: 0xff00ff }
})
```